# ASP ImageButton open new page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, imagebutton

I have this ImageButton (that actually open the link in the same page)

```html
<asp:ImageButton ID="LinkNewItem" CssClass="AlignedTextBox" ToolTip="Add new Item" ImageUrl="~/TESTPROJECT/edit.gif"
         runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/TESTPROJECT/PageTest.aspx" />
```

I need that it will open a new page (like `target='_blank'`).
I tried to insert it in cs but it doesn't work.

```
LinkNewItem.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
```

How can I use that tag to open a new page with automatic refresh at closing?

Thanks so much

Comment: I don't think you can do a PostBack to a different url and open a new windows at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to implement that because the `ImageButton` will try to make a post, whereas you are trying to perform a get in a new tab.

You can do 2 things:

Implement that using the `OnClientClick` attribute:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="LinkNewItem" CssClass="AlignedTextBox" ToolTip="Add new Item" 
         OnClientClick="window.open('/TESTPROJECT/edit.gif')
         runat="server"/>
```

Use a Hyperlink instead:

```
<asp:hyperlink id="link" runat="server" NavigateUrl="foo">
   <asp:image id="img" runat="server" imageurl="yourimage" />
</asp:hyperlink>
```